# Computer beeps at boot 3 times and loads Windows

Tags: windows-7, boot, memory, motherboard, bios

Just recently for the last 3 weeks, my desktop PC is beeping at boot and then boots Windows successfully. When I am on the PC, I don't see any issues at all.
The beeps are short and as follows.

**beep beep beep - PAUSE (1 second) - beep beep beep - PAUSE (1 second) - beep beep beep** and boots Windows.

I looked around on the internet for information on this, but so far I have not found anything similar to my beeps. I am thinking my memory card is going bad. What do you think?

Comment: What is your computer model, your motherboard and BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: I built the computer myself. It wasn't bought off shelf.

Comment: Without the above information it's impossible to proceed.